# Flutter painting package missing BeveledRectangleBorder class

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm following the flutter shrine [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-103-flutter/#6) from google but i'm stuck at this point (page 7):

```
FlatButton(
  child: Text('CANCEL'),
  shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(7.0)),
),
```

because apparently the flutter [painting](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/painting-library.html) package is missing the [BeveledRectangleBorder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BeveledRectangleBorder-class.html) class; does anyone knows how to fix it?

p.s. I'm using android studio with the flutter plugin v28.0.1 that seems to be the last release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to update your fluter framework.
This is different from Flutter plugin in andorid studio.

To know the version of framework inside Android studio. 
`Go to preferences -> Under Language & framework section -> click on flutter`. And see the version you are on. It should not be below `0.6.0`

To update the framework from Android studio open `pubspec.yaml` file from your project structure. You will see flutter commands on top of the file with 4 options. Click on `Flutter upgrade` & wait for the framework to update.

This should solve your problem.